openvpn : can't connect with distinct certificates when more than ~20 users
I have setup a VPN for my students to access some boxes ;
here is the server configuration :
port 1194
port-share 172.17.16.12 80
proto tcp
dev tun
ca       /.../.crt
cert     /.../.crt
key      /../.key
dh       /etc/openvpn/CA/dh/dh2048.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/CA/static_key/static.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 10.128.41.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.10.71.0 255.255.255.0"
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-GCM
data-ciphers AES-256-GCM
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
auth SHA512
#comp-lzo adaptive
max-clients 100
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log-append  /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 6
mute 20

when i authorize the students to use a shared configuration (with same private keys) all is good (but still bad practice).
Client side configuration looks like this :
tls-client
auth-nocache
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote A.B.C.D 80
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher AES-256-GCM
#comp-lzo adaptive
verb 5
auth SHA512
<ca>...
</ca>
<cert>
</cert>
<key>
</key>
<tls-auth>
</tls-auth>

Messages on log do not differ from other successfully connected users.
I can't see anything wrong in configuration.
Many thanks for helping !

So what's in server log when 21st client connects? What in the client log?
